# Both extract and create names for columns within a matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a matrix with columns denoting 30 different frequency windows and rows denoting dates. I would like to extract each column and assign a variable to each resulting vector and have the name of that variable be the name of that frequency window (which I have in center values, so I'd like to name each variable something like f100). What is the best way to write a loop to both extract and name each variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show a small example dataset and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create 30 variables in the global environment from the columns of the matrix, you could use `list2env` or `assign` (I would probably keep it together in a matrix/dataframe or even in a list and do all the necessary operations rather than cluttering the global environment with lots of variables).

```
 list2env(lapply(as.data.frame(mat), function(x) x), envir=.GlobalEnv)
 # <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

 f1
 #[1] 37 38 12 34 26 21 30  6 27 29
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
 mat <- matrix(sample(1:40, 30*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=30, 
                        dimnames=list(NULL, paste0("f", 1:30)))
```